# Two nodes at the maximum distance in a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

I am stuck up with a modified version of the problem ( Find two nodes located at a distance k in a binary tree).

I was trying to define the distance between two nodes and I believe that it is the minimum number of nodes needed to travel from node n1 to node n2 along the tree branches.

Well proceeding with this assumption, I arrived at a situation where I believe I need to know for each node if it is to the left or right of the root.

Case1 : If n1 and n2 are on different side then I climb to the root ( distance equals to depth of the node n1 - assuming n1 is on left) and then I run down to the right node n2 ( distance equals to the depth of n2). So the maximum distance between two nodes n1 , n2 is the sum of their depths if they are on different sides of the root.

Case 2 : If n1 and n2 are on the same side, I find an ancestor common to both in the tree hierarchy and repeat the same process considering the ancestor a root as I did in the case 1.
The minimum distance will be the sum of their depths from root - 2 times the depth of common ancestor.

Now, the problem with this is, I end up doing this for every pair of node bluntly. I can optimize it to not check a pair if I know a pair of node which are at a distance more than this but how?

Please suggest the rest of the solution.

Comment: what about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134583/looking-for-fast-algorithm-to-find-distance-between-two-nodes-in-binary-tree

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as [Diameter of a Binary Tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/5687)(see the bottom up approach) which is defined as the number of nodes on the longest path between two leaves in the tree. In your case you have to find out nodes as well.