# Applying bfs on a tree to find the longest path between two vertices

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

In a tree I have to find two vertices which have maximum number of vertices between them (connected) including both of them. Then I need to find the total number of vertices between them. I want to approach this problem using Breadth first search algorithm, but not getting any clue. How to handle this?

example(for 5 nodes)- the tree links are:

1-2

1-3

3-4

3-5

then the longest path is
2-1-3-4 or 2-1-3-5
thus this path has in total 4 vertices.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134583/looking-for-fast-algorithm-to-find-distance-between-two-nodes-in-binary-tree

Comment: @Leeor i want the BFS approach to solve this problem

Comment: @Leeor u have provided a link to a LCA problem.Is it the same thing?

Comment: Since on a tree each 2 vertices have a single path, the distance between each 2 is the sum of distances from the LCA.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use adjacency matrix.
The idea is to make adjacency matrix for each node making it as source node, i.e. in your example total 5. 
Then navigate each matrix and find out the maximum connected node for that node. Put the tracking path of the largest value in stack, for future use.
Repeat this process until you have covered all the matrix. Compare the results from all the matrix. The one with the largest value is the one to choose and its corresponding value in stack is the given path.
It can be also solved using dynamic programming. Please see the link below which explains the Floyds Warshall algorithm. Please see the way it finds the shortest path using dynamic programming. you can tweak some part of it to find the solution to your problem using DP.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMAoMMsA5Jg

-Bhupesh

Comment: Bhupesh- u mean i have to create different matrix for each node?

Comment: and do u mean applying BFS to find out the maximum connected node?

Comment: @bhupeshi guess it would be much simpler if i use adjacency list and then apply bfs for every node and note down the max distance it travels

Comment: Sorry for replying late to your post.
Yes you have to create different matrix for each node. Since you are not sure of the two nodes. If you are sure you can just do it by putting that node in the first place. For e.g. if you wanted to know the longest path from the given node, 3 then you will need only one matrix. This matrix should start from 3  as its first element for easy navigation of vertices.

Comment: Yes I am using BFS for this. You are right, you can also use list for this but I prefer using matrix for small application and test progs. its easy to use and understand as well. and once you understand you can use any datastructure to suit your needs.I can recall that one of the DS book I referred when I was in college, DS through C by yashwant K has an example exactly similar to your problem. You can refer that if you need.

Comment: what if i am using adjacency list?then i have to traverse for every node and it would save space as well

Comment: whaqt if the tree contains any cycle?

Comment: DO you mean node containing cycle or tree containing?BTW yours is a undirected graph so cycles should not bother at tree level....

Comment: Does that answer your question...I know a good link for you..that clearly says the uses of BFS...and it says
Breath­First Search Applications
● Shortest path
● Single­Source shortest paths
● All­Pairs shortest path

so you can simple tweak the logic a bit to serve your purpose..

Comment: i am coding it right now as u said.i will post the code in some time

Comment: yes also it would be helpful for me if you can add comments on your use cases of your requirement...Its still bit unclear..

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a tree, a BFS run from any source node will simply return the same tree with your source as root (not so with a generic graph, where BFS may ignore edges that create a shorter path between the 2 nodes you want to compare).

You want the two farthest away vertices, for any given root, these may be on different branches (in which case you could find the farthest leaf on each brach), or they could be on the same branch (in which case you could continue on that subtree. However this involves a form of DP that is slightly more than BFS alone.

You could try to run a single BFS run from an arbitrary root, add back edges (each child points to the father), and then propagate back the longest found leaf on each branch to the parent. On the way up calculate the max distance for each sub tree on the way, and if the parent has a higher dinstance available due to cross-branch distance - replace the local max.

I have to admit however, that at this point the difference from just a BFS is quite substantial.